# Past tense with modals in reported speech

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives, reported-speech

> — "If I *could have gone* to college I *would have done* this."

How would you report this speech? I would do it the following way. But note that nothing actually changes in the verbs and I can't think of any way to make a change.

> — "He said that if he *could have gone* to college he *would have done* this."

Comment: That's right. The language has no double past inflection or construction. But does it really need one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually change the verbs here to indicate reported speech; although you may change the meaning.

> He said that had he gone to college, he would have done this.

This changes the conditional aspect of the statement slightly. It removes the implication of the lack of opportunity, so it transforms the meaning subtly. This says nothing, one way or the other, about whether this person faced barriers in obtaining an education.

> He said that had he had the opportunity to go [to have gone] to college, he would
>   have done this.

And while this is closer to the original statement semantically, it's a tad awkward with *had had.*

> He said that, had he the opportunity to go [to have gone] to college, he would have done this.

*Had he had the opportunity* and *had he the opportunity* are semantically equivalent to *if he could have*, but they might be more awkward.

And *to go* is much less awkward in **my** examples, but *to have gone* is also grammatical. I included *have gone* in brackets because it's obviously more reflective of the speech being attributed.

By the way, I'd suggest using *would have done so* for the reported speech. It's just a more common usage, but it's your choice.

Comment: I like the way *"had he gone to college"* sounds. It sounds perfectly natural, and much better than what I originally thought (and didn't dare to post), *He said that if he were able to have gone to college, he would have done this,* which is pretty awkward imho.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I actually prefer *had he* and *had he had* to *if he had* as well, but it's just my personal preference (I also prefer *should/could he* to *if he should/could*). *If* is actually extraneous in conditionals. But I think that because this is reported speech, it needs to stay closer to the original; otherwise, in much the same way, your sentence could be written as ***Were he able** to attend college, he would have done this/it/so.* The only thing wrong with your sentence, in essence, is that it's not quite what was originally said.